# Mistake in the Asc() VB function?

Tags: vb.net, string

Could you please tell why the Asc() function returns incorrect result?

```
    Dim TestChar = Chr(128)
    Dim CharInt = Asc(TestChar) ' this is a mistake on Windows 7 x64. Asc(TestChar) returns 136 instead of 128
```

I executed this code on another computer and the result was 128.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your computer is using a different default code page.

The `Asc` function uses the system's current ANSI code page.
The `Chr` function simply casts the value to `char`.  (Unless it's `> 255`)

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure if this is the cause, because .NET generally always uses Unicode. Unless this is some retardation they carried over from VB6, of course. Would be another good reason for *VB.NET not to exist.*

Comment: @Matti: Yes, this is from VB6.

Comment: Surely this can't be the whole story? `Asc` uses the current ANSI code page, but so does `Chr`: it converts an ANSI code-point number into a character (I think this is best called a *conversion* not a *cast*). So I believe `Asc(Chr(X))` would always return X? I've tried Alexander's snippet with Chinese code page, and `Asc(TestChar)` is 128. Perhaps in fact Alexander was running `Asc` with one code page and then later - or on another computer - `Chr` with another code page?

Comment: @MarkJ: `Chr` does a standard type-cast.  (Unless it's `> 255`)  Look at it in Reflector.

Comment: @SLaks again. To summarise the last comment. If `(char) X` can be called a standard type-cast, then `Chr(X)` surely can't be called a standard type-cast, because it has different behaviour?

Comment: @MarkJ: Check Reflector.  It has the same behavior for characters that are `< 255`.  **EDIT** : I take that back.  It has uses a cast for `< 128`.

Comment: @SLaks. OK, that makes sense. I think `<128` is the same on all code pages and is the same as the Unicode values. By the way I did actually *run* the tests in my comments so I wasn't that concerned to look in Reflector. I still think the code snippet in Alexander's question can't be the whole story, but he seems to be happy...

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this exact code on Windows 7 x64 with Visual Studio 2010 and got the expected value of 128.  I tried mixing options (Infer, explicit, etc ...) and the value remains the same.  Can you provide some more details to help track this down?

```
Sub Main()
    Dim TestChar = Chr(128)
    Dim CharInt = Asc(TestChar)
    Console.WriteLine(CharInt)
    Stop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I used the different default code page. I changed it into the English and code works fine.
Thank you!